# Inserting a blank row after predetermined number of rows in php

Tags: php, tcpdf

Here's what i want, after a group of say 3 rows in table i insert a blank row
Here's my code for creating the tables and populating with data

```
    $row_count =0;
    while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        $row_count++;

            $tbl .=' <tr>                                   

                      <td>' .'&nbsp;' .$data['houseNumber'].'</td>
                      <td>' .'&nbsp;'.$data['tenantName'].'</td>
                      <td>' .'&nbsp;'.$data['status'].'</td>                      
                      <td>' .'&nbsp;'.$data['rentDue'].'</td>                      
                      <td>' .'&nbsp;'.$data['rentPaid'].'</td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>'.'&nbsp;' .($data['rentPaid']).'</td>


                  </tr> ';      

                }//end while
```

How can i use this `$row_count` variable to do that. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: `if ($row_count == ) { insertRow }`

Comment: `if ($row_count%3 == 0 ) { insertRow }`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$row_count =0;
while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row_count++;
    $tbl .=' <tr>                                   
        <td>' .'&nbsp;' .$data['houseNumber'].'</td>
        <td>' .'&nbsp;'.$data['tenantName'].'</td>
        <td>' .'&nbsp;'.$data['status'].'</td>                      
        <td>' .'&nbsp;'.$data['rentDue'].'</td>                      
        <td>' .'&nbsp;'.$data['rentPaid'].'</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>'.'&nbsp;' .($data['rentPaid']).'</td>
    </tr> ';     

    if ($row_count % 3 == 0) { 
        //if is divisible for 3, put the blanck row
        $tbl .=' <tr>                                   
            <td colspan="9">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr> ';        
    } 
}
//end while
```